# grpc call on on Https not working in python

Tags: python, https, grpc

I have hosted grpc service on https where i don't have any certificate file locally.
How can i call grpc secure channel call to my address

'''
grpc.secure_channel('https://myapplication.net') ?
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was having https:// in the address. when removed it like

```
with grpc.secure_channel('mybaseaddress.abc.net',grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()) as channel:
```

it worked